# Getting error "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common"

Tags: java, ssl

I made standalone server using SSLServersocket which is used for  printing the html content in to the pdf format but while making the request from POSTMAN to SERVER, i am getting above mention error that is "**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common**". I have attached all the source code file and the debug log of the server.  I am new to this Socket programming

NewTest.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.exceptions.RuntimeWorkerException;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerFontProvider;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.StyleAttrCSSResolver;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.CssAppliersImpl;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.Tags;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.end.PdfWriterPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipelineContext;
import com.server.Printer;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Paper;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.attribute.AttributeSet;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.printing.PDFPageable;

public class NewTest {
    public static final String HTML = "posPrint/";
    public static final String PDF = "posPrint/";
    public static final String FONTFORMAT = "posPrint/font.ttf";
    public static final String CSSSTYLE = "posPrint/css1.css";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        NewTest server = new NewTest();
        server.run();
    }

    private void run() throws IOException {
        SSLServerSocket socket = null;
        try {
            SSLContext sc=SSLContext.getDefault();
            SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
            socket =(SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(7655);
        } catch (IOException |NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Server is  running");

        while (true)  {
            Socket sock = socket.accept();
            InputStreamReader IR = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(IR);

            StringBuilder payload = new StringBuilder();

            while (bufferedReader.ready()) {
                payload.append((char) bufferedReader.read());
            }

            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            if (payload.length() > 1) {
                Printer printer = (Printer) mapper.readValue(payload.toString(), Printer.class);
                FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(HTML + printer.uid + ".html");
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
                writer.write(printer.content);
                writer.close();
                String fileName = PDF + printer.uid + ".pdf";

                try {
                    printPdf(fileName, printer.size);
                    print(printer.nameOfPrinter, printer.noOfCopies, fileName);

                    out.write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
                    out.write("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n");
                    out.write("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization\r\n");
                    out.write("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-type\r\n");
                    out.write("Content-type: text/plain\r\n");
                    out.write("s");
                    out.close();
                    sock.close();
                    File file = new File(fileName);
                    Files.deleteIfExists(file.toPath());
                } catch (IOException | RuntimeWorkerException
                        arg11) {
                    arg11.printStackTrace();
                    out.write("HTTP/1.0 500 ERROR\r\n");
                    out.write("\r\n");
                    out.write("<TITLE>Print Utility</TITLE>");
                    out.write(arg11.toString());
                    out.close();
                    sock.close();
                }
            } else {
                out.write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
                out.write("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n");
                out.write("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization\r\n");
                out.write("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-type\r\n");
                out.write("s");
                out.close();
                sock.close();
            }

        }
    }

    private static void printPdf(String pdfName, double width)  {
        File file = new File(pdfName);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle((float) width*72, 590.0F);
        Document document = new Document(pagesize, 0F, 0F, 0F, 15F);
        PdfWriter writer;
        try {
            writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
            document.open();
            StyleAttrCSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
            cssResolver.addCss(XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(new FileInputStream(CSSSTYLE)));
            XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider("?");
            fontProvider.register(FONTFORMAT);
            CssAppliersImpl cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
            HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
            htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
            PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
            HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
            CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);
            XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
            XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
            p.parse(new FileInputStream(HTML), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            document.close();
        } catch (IOException | DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static boolean print(String nameOFPrinter, int noOFCopies, String pdf)
         {
        File file = new File(pdf);
        PDDocument document;
        try {
            document = PDDocument.load(file);
            PrintService myPrintService = findPrintService(nameOFPrinter);
            PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));

            if (myPrintService == null) {
                myPrintService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
                if (myPrintService == null) {
                    document.close();
                    return false;
                }
            }

            job.setPrintService(myPrintService);
            job.setCopies(noOFCopies);
            job.print();
            document.close();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException |PrinterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }

    private static PrintService findPrintService(String printerName) {
        PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices((DocFlavor) null, (AttributeSet) null);
        PrintService[] arg4 = printServices;
        int arg3 = printServices.length;

        for (int arg2 = 0; arg2 < arg3; ++arg2) {
            PrintService printService = arg4[arg2];
            if (printService.getName().trim().equals(printerName)) {
                return printService;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Printer.java

```
public class Printer {
    int noOfCopies;
    String nameOfPrinter;
    String content;
    double size;
    String uid;
    String fileName;

    public int getNoOfCopies() {
        return noOfCopies;
    }

    public void setNoOfCopies(int noOfCopies) {
        this.noOfCopies = noOfCopies;
    }

    public String getNameOfPrinter() {
        return nameOfPrinter;
    }

    public void setNameOfPrinter(String nameOfPrinter) {
        this.nameOfPrinter = nameOfPrinter;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public double getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(double size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getUID() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUID(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Printer [noOfCopies=" + noOfCopies + ", nameOfPrinter=" + nameOfPrinter + ", content=" + content + "]";
    }

}
```

I have created the jar file of tbe above code and run that jar with the below code

```
java -Djavax.net.debug=ssl -jar TEST.jar

Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is :
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xc3517
  Valid from Mon Jun 21 09:30:00 IST 1999 until Mon Jun 22 09:30:00 IST 2020

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - EC1, OU="(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - EC1, OU="(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: EC; Serial number: 0xa68b79290000000050d091f9
  Valid from Tue Dec 18 20:55:36 IST 2012 until Fri Dec 18 21:25:36 IST 2037

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=SecureTrust CA, O=SecureTrust Corporation, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=SecureTrust CA, O=SecureTrust Corporation, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xcf08e5c0816a5ad427ff0eb271859d0
  Valid from Wed Nov 08 01:01:18 IST 2006 until Tue Jan 01 01:10:55 IST 2030

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=Security Communication RootCA1, O=SECOM Trust.net, C=JP
  Issuer:  OU=Security Communication RootCA1, O=SECOM Trust.net, C=JP
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
  Valid from Tue Sep 30 09:50:49 IST 2003 until Sat Sep 30 09:50:49 IST 2023

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x83be056904246b1a1756ac95991c74a
  Valid from Fri Nov 10 05:30:00 IST 2006 until Mon Nov 10 05:30:00 IST 2031

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=QuoVadis Root CA 2 G3, O=QuoVadis Limited, C=BM
  Issuer:  CN=QuoVadis Root CA 2 G3, O=QuoVadis Limited, C=BM
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x445734245b81899b35f2ceb82b3b5ba726f07528
  Valid from Fri Jan 13 00:29:32 IST 2012 until Mon Jan 13 00:29:32 IST 2042

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Trusted Root G4, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Trusted Root G4, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x59b1b579e8e2132e23907bda777755c
  Valid from Thu Aug 01 17:30:00 IST 2013 until Fri Jan 15 17:30:00 IST 2038

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x18acb56afd69b6153a636cafdafac4a1
  Valid from Mon Nov 27 05:30:00 IST 2006 until Thu Jul 17 05:29:59 IST 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=Security Communication RootCA2, O="SECOM Trust Systems CO.,LTD.", C=JP
  Issuer:  OU=Security Communication RootCA2, O="SECOM Trust Systems CO.,LTD.", C=JP
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
  Valid from Fri May 29 10:30:39 IST 2009 until Tue May 29 10:30:39 IST 2029

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x7dd9fe07cfa81eb7107967fba78934c6
  Valid from Mon May 18 05:30:00 IST 1998 until Wed Aug 02 05:29:59 IST 2028

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=ePKI Root Certification Authority, O="Chunghwa Telecom Co., Ltd.", C=TW
  Issuer:  OU=ePKI Root Certification Authority, O="Chunghwa Telecom Co., Ltd.", C=TW
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x15c8bd65475cafb897005ee406d2bc9d
  Valid from Mon Dec 20 08:01:27 IST 2004 until Wed Dec 20 08:01:27 IST 2034

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=AffirmTrust Commercial, O=AffirmTrust, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=AffirmTrust Commercial, O=AffirmTrust, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x7777062726a9b17c
  Valid from Fri Jan 29 19:36:06 IST 2010 until Tue Dec 31 19:36:06 IST 2030

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Certum Trusted Network CA, OU=Certum Certification Authority, O=Unizeto Technologies S.A., C=PL
  Issuer:  CN=Certum Trusted Network CA, OU=Certum Certification Authority, O=Unizeto Technologies S.A., C=PL
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x444c0
  Valid from Wed Oct 22 17:37:37 IST 2008 until Mon Dec 31 17:37:37 IST 2029

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=XRamp Global Certification Authority, O=XRamp Security Services Inc, OU=www.xrampsecurity.com, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=XRamp Global Certification Authority, O=XRamp Security Services Inc, OU=www.xrampsecurity.com, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x50946cec18ead59c4dd597ef758fa0ad
  Valid from Mon Nov 01 22:44:04 IST 2004 until Mon Jan 01 11:07:19 IST 2035

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Sonera Class2 CA, O=Sonera, C=FI
  Issuer:  CN=Sonera Class2 CA, O=Sonera, C=FI
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1d
  Valid from Fri Apr 06 12:59:40 IST 2001 until Tue Apr 06 12:59:40 IST 2021

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=America Online Root Certification Authority 1, O=America Online Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=America Online Root Certification Authority 1, O=America Online Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Tue May 28 11:30:00 IST 2002 until Fri Nov 20 02:13:00 IST 2037

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G2, OU=(c) 2007 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G2, OU=(c) 2007 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: EC; Serial number: 0x3cb2f4480a00e2feeb243b5e603ec36b
  Valid from Mon Nov 05 05:30:00 IST 2007 until Tue Jan 19 05:29:59 IST 2038

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US
  Issuer:  OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x35def4cf
  Valid from Sat Aug 22 22:11:51 IST 1998 until Wed Aug 22 22:11:51 IST 2018

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=COMODO ECC Certification Authority, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  Issuer:  CN=COMODO ECC Certification Authority, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  Algorithm: EC; Serial number: 0x1f47afaa62007050544c019e9b63992a
  Valid from Thu Mar 06 05:30:00 IST 2008 until Tue Jan 19 05:29:59 IST 2038

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=ISRG Root X1, O=Internet Security Research Group, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=ISRG Root X1, O=Internet Security Research Group, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x8210cfb0d240e3594463e0bb63828b00
  Valid from Thu Jun 04 16:34:38 IST 2015 until Mon Jun 04 16:34:38 IST 2035

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x2ac5c266a0b409b8f0b79f2ae462577
  Valid from Fri Nov 10 05:30:00 IST 2006 until Mon Nov 10 05:30:00 IST 2031

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust Universal CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Universal CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Thu Mar 04 10:30:00 IST 2004 until Sun Mar 04 10:30:00 IST 2029

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  Issuer:  CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4000000000121585308a2
  Valid from Wed Mar 18 15:30:00 IST 2009 until Sun Mar 18 15:30:00 IST 2029

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root, OU=CyberTrust, O=Baltimore, C=IE
  Issuer:  CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root, OU=CyberTrust, O=Baltimore, C=IE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x20000b9
  Valid from Sat May 13 00:16:00 IST 2000 until Tue May 13 05:29:00 IST 2025

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Thawte Timestamping CA, OU=Thawte Certification, O=Thawte, L=Durbanville, ST=Western Cape, C=ZA
  Issuer:  CN=Thawte Timestamping CA, OU=Thawte Certification, O=Thawte, L=Durbanville, ST=Western Cape, C=ZA
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x67c8e1e8e3be1cbdfc913b8ea6238749
  Valid from Wed Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1997 until Sat Jan 02 05:29:59 IST 2021

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Global Chambersign Root - 2008, O=AC Camerfirma S.A., SERIALNUMBER=A82743287, L=Madrid (see current address at www.camerfirma.com/address), C=EU
  Issuer:  CN=Global Chambersign Root - 2008, O=AC Camerfirma S.A., SERIALNUMBER=A82743287, L=Madrid (see current address at www.camerfirma.com/address), C=EU
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xc9cdd3e9d57d23ce
  Valid from Fri Aug 01 18:01:40 IST 2008 until Sat Jul 31 18:01:40 IST 2038

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=thawte Primary Root CA - G3, OU="(c) 2008 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Certification Services Division, O="thawte, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  CN=thawte Primary Root CA - G3, OU="(c) 2008 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Certification Services Division, O="thawte, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x600197b746a7eab4b49ad64b2ff790fb
  Valid from Wed Apr 02 05:30:00 IST 2008 until Wed Dec 02 05:29:59 IST 2037

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  Issuer:  CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4caaf9cadb636fe01ff74ed85b03869d
  Valid from Tue Jan 19 05:30:00 IST 2010 until Tue Jan 19 05:29:59 IST 2038

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GTE CyberTrust Global Root, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GTE CyberTrust Global Root, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1a5
  Valid from Thu Aug 13 05:59:00 IST 1998 until Tue Aug 14 05:29:00 IST 2018

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=premium-server@thawte.com, CN=Thawte Premium Server CA, OU=Certification Services Division, O=Thawte Consulting cc, L=Cape Town, ST=Western Cape, C=ZA
  Issuer:  EMAILADDRESS=premium-server@thawte.com, CN=Thawte Premium Server CA, OU=Certification Services Division, O=Thawte Consulting cc, L=Cape Town, ST=Western Cape, C=ZA
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x36122296c5e338a520a1d25f4cd70954
  Valid from Thu Aug 01 05:30:00 IST 1996 until Sat Jan 02 05:29:59 IST 2021


adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4cc7eaaa983e71d39310f83d3a899192
  Valid from Mon May 18 05:30:00 IST 1998 until Wed Aug 02 05:29:59 IST 2028


adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Global Root G2, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Global Root G2, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x33af1e6a711a9a0bb2864b11d09fae5
  Valid from Thu Aug 01 17:30:00 IST 2013 until Fri Jan 15 17:30:00 IST 2038

keyStore is :
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is :
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Server is  running
```

Please find below the  error stack trace after making request from postman-

```
   Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.close(Unknown Source)
    at com.server.NewTest.run(NewTest.java:131)
    at com.server.NewTest.main(NewTest.java:63)
```

I have attached the screenshot of request from postman-[Request from POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLc3I.png)

Comment: It would be much helpful for the stack community to analyze and give you the necessary suggestions if you could point us to the code snippets where you are thinking there might be a issue rather than pasting the entire source code.

Comment: Possibly related to the certificate you are using.

Comment: There *is* no keystore, no server certificate, no private key, so the server is unable to negotiate a cipher suite.